# How to add recyclerview item in favorites Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, favorite

I have Android application that stores information from `SQLite` database in a `RecyclerView`. I have a button on every `RecyclerView` item that when clicked on should add the item to favorites, this list of favorites must be avaible to the user when needed. a bit like whatsapp or gmail.

How to implement this please?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of what you've done already

Comment: I only add a favorite button that changes color to click for the rest no idea

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the button you can save the favorite state to your sqlite database table, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged(position)` on the RecyclerViews `Adapter` this will update the data on the `RecyclerView`

Comment: I already done that. what i want is to add item to the favorite.

Comment: What do you mean by favorite. favorite in the database or in another view ?

Comment: In another view!

Comment: @Mavis you can try and use https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus to send a message to update the list